# raspberry pi B2台をBluetooth接続したい

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth

タイトルの通りraspberry pi B 2台をBluetooth接続したいです．

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# agent DisplayYesNo
[bluetooth]# pair <addr>
Attempting to pair with <addr>
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
[bluetooth]# connect <addr>
Attempting to connect to <addr>
[CHG]Device <addr> Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG]Device <addr> Connected: no
```

となり，以降接続が確立されることはありません．
対策として

```
[bluetooth]# remove <addr>
```

で再度scan onからデバイス接続を行ったり，

```
sudo reboot
```

で再起動したりしましたが結果は変わりません．

bluetoothドングルとして，
iBuffalo Bluetooth 4.0+EDR/LE
を用いています．
何か同じ問題を抱えている方，アドバイスいただければありがたいです．

Answer (score 2):

解決いたしました．
接続確立させるのは諦めて，ペアリング後すぐに以下のコマンドを実行しシリアルポート通信を行うことができました．

```
raspberrypi#1$ sudo rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 22
```

`raspberrypi#2$ sudo rfcomm connect <addr#1> 22`

どうも単に接続確立するのは不可能で，自身が提供しているサービスを公開した後に接続確立する必要があったみたいです．